# Perform dig on two lists

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I need to run a dig on domains and these domains aliases, so the result will be: 
IF domain (+ doesn't have an alias) and is using my Name Servers -> then print out 
IF both domain and alias are using my Name Servers -> then print out 
Everything else no (including when domain is using my Name Servers and alias don't).
I have domains stored in MySQL and there's the script I am working on:

```
for domain in `echo "$QUERY1" | mysql -N -s -u $USER -p$PASS $DBNAME -h$HOST | awk '{print $1}'; do
    lookup=$(dig $domain ns +short)
    if [[ "$lookup" =~ 'XXX' ]]; then
        our=1
        break
    else
        our=0
        break
    fi
done
```

In this QUERY I am listing everything (both domains and aliases). I can of course create another query to list only aliases or only domains.
It would seem that I would need to group together all the aliases of the domain and loop over the domain name + aliases list. If either one not using NS, I would have to set variable that dictates printing the domain.
Let me know, what are your ideas and please share the solution, if possible.

Comment: Have you considered using `dig` directly for all of this?  It has a batch mode, `dig -f filename`, which is probably exactly what you need.  You can use e.g. Awk to parse the query results and generate the batch file.

Comment: Also, regarding the shell snippet in your question, I highly recommend reading [Why is printf better than echo?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/135943) and [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/135943)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following alternative to the script you're working on:

```
mysql --silent --skip-column-names \
    --user="$USER" --password="$PASSWORD" \
    --host="$HOST" --database="$DBNAME" \
    --execute="$QUERY1" |
awk '{ printf("%s ns +short\n", $1) }' |
if dig -f - | grep -q "XXX"; then
    our=1
else
    our=0
fi
```

I prefer using the long options in scripts since they are self-documenting.

The query in `$QUERY1` can be crafted in such a way that the `awk` isn't necessary:

```
SELECT CONCAT(column, " ns +short") FROM ...
```

I've made `dig` read its queries from standard input out of the pipe coming from `awk` and the `grep` helps us finding `XXX` in the output.

No messy looping required.

Obviously, it doesn't do what you want to do at the end, only what you do at the moment, but since I don't know too much about DNS lookups I'll leave it at that.